# CSS media query for the Google Pixel phones?

Tags: css

Can someone tell me the width and height in px (as used by CSS in mobile mode) for the Pixel and Pixel LG?

Surprised that the Pixels do not yet appear as options in Chrome's emulator! Note that I'm not asking for the tech specs that can be found on the Pixel website.

Answer (score 1):

The specs for the Google Pixel are :

- 1140px x 2560px
- 441dp x 731dp
- 16:9 ratio

If you want to target it with media queries:

@media  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.77) and (orientation:landscape) // or (orientation:portrait) {}

Works for me, but it also reach other mobiles like the recent Galaxy's.